# Check if a string is a float

Tags: python, string

I am suppose to take in an input and return true or false depending on whether the input is a valid number.  Here are some examples:

```
"0" => true
" 0.1 " => true
"abc" => false
"1 a" => false
"2e10" => true
" -90e3   " => true
" 1e" => false
"e3" => false
" 6e-1" => true
" 99e2.5 " => false
"53.5e93" => true
" --6 " => false
"-+3" => false
"95a54e53" => false
```

I have a list of all of the valid characters and I decided to use slicing notation to see which character in the 0th index of the input matches any of the valid ones.  However, the code is misreading the input `9` as false.  This is my full code at the moment.  I haven't yet checked for all conditions:

```
class Solution:
    def isNumber(self, s: str) -> bool:
        valid_char = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '+', 'e', '.']
        str_lst = list(s)

        if str_lst[0] in valid_char[0:10]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go for this in my opinion is using a `try`/`except` clause to try to cast the strings to `float`:

> ```
> "0" => true
> " 0.1 " => true
> "abc" => false
> "1 a" => false
> "2e10" => true
> " -90e3   " => true
> " 1e" => false
> "e3" => false
> " 6e-1" => true
> " 99e2.5 " => false
> "53.5e93" => true
> " --6 " => false
> "-+3" => false
> "95a54e53" => false
> ```

---

Let's generate a list with the strings above:

```
l = ["0", " 0.1 ", "abc", "1 a", "2e10", " -90e3   ", " 1e", "e3", 
     " 6e-1", " 99e2.5 ", "53.5e93", " --6 ", "-+3", "95a54e53"]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

list(map(is_number, l))
# [True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, 
#  True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: This is pretty smart. You're basically using the Python's error mechanism as a part of your code without having to build an entire algorithm to see if each char is valid. I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 3):

Well first off there is no need to convert `s` to `str(s)` if you're not planing to change `s`, which you're probably not going to. Slicing works pretty much the same on strings as it does on lists. If you really want to check if `s` is a valid python number you can use

```py
inp = input('input character: ')
def is_valid_num(s):
    try: 
        float(inp)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: I've already accepted yatu's answer but I'll give you an upvote for the correct approach.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah it's a kind of well known approach to this situation.